# How to put $(-\sqrt{3}-i)^{\frac{5}{7}}$ into polar form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to put $(-\sqrt{3}-i)^{\frac{5}{7}}$ into polar form and find all roots.

What I tried:

$$w = -\sqrt{3}-i$$
$$\arg(w)=\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})-\pi = \frac{\pi}{6} - \pi = \frac{-5\pi}{6}$$
$$w = 2(\cos(\frac{-5\pi}{6})+ i\sin(\frac{-5\pi}{6})) $$
$$w^5 = 2^5(\cos(-\frac{5\pi}{6}*5)+i\sin(-\frac{5\pi}{6}*5)) $$
$$z^7 = w^5$$
$$z = w^{\frac{5}{7}} $$
$$z = 32^{\frac{1}{7}}(\cos(\frac{-5\pi*5}{6*7}+\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\sin(\frac{-5\pi*5}{6*7}+\frac{2k\pi}{7})) $$
Here I get stuck and I don't know how to continue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to express in exponential, rather than cis, form.  Considering only the normalized complex number for brevity:

$$\begin{align*}
  w &= \text{e}^{(-\frac{5}{6} \pi +2 \pi k) i} \\
  w^5 &= \text{e}^{(-\frac{25}{6} \pi + 10 \pi k) i} = \text{e}^{(-\frac{25}{6} \pi + 2 \pi k) i} \\
  z^7 &= w^5 \\
  w^{\frac{5}{7}} &= \text{e}^{(-\frac{25}{42} \pi + \frac{2}{7} \pi k) i} \\
\end{align*}
$$

Now we enumerate through the 7 unique roots of unity, these are:

$$
\begin{align*}
  w^{\frac{5}{7}}_0 &= \text{e}^{-\frac{25}{42} \pi i} \approx -0.294755 - 0.955573 i \\
  w^{\frac{5}{7}}_1 &= \text{e}^{(\frac{2}{7} -\frac{25}{42}) \pi i}  = \text{e}^{-\frac{13}{42} \pi i} \approx 0.56332 - 0.826239 i \\
  w^{\frac{5}{7}}_2 &= \text{e}^{(\frac{4}{7} -\frac{25}{42}) \pi i}  = \text{e}^{-\frac{1}{42} \pi i} \approx 0.997204 - 0.0747301 i \\
  w^{\frac{5}{7}}_3 &= \text{e}^{(\frac{6}{7} -\frac{25}{42}) \pi i}  = \text{e}^{\frac{11}{42} \pi i} \approx 0.680173 + 0.733052 i \\
  w^{\frac{5}{7}}_4 &= \text{e}^{(\frac{8}{7} -\frac{25}{42}) \pi i} = \text{e}^{\frac{23}{42} \pi i} \approx -0.149042 + 0.988831 i \\
  w^{\frac{5}{7}}_5 &= \text{e}^{(\frac{10}{7} -\frac{25}{42}) \pi i} = \text{e}^{\frac{5}{6} \pi i} \approx -0.866025 + 0.5 i \\
  w^{\frac{5}{7}}_6 &= \text{e}^{(\frac{12}{7} -\frac{25}{42}) \pi i} = \text{e}^{-\frac{37}{42} \pi i} \approx -0.930874 - 0.365341 i \\
\end{align*}
$$

Beyond this, we wind up with $\frac{14}{7} \pi$ which is just $2 \pi$ and so the roots repeat.

And here they are plotted:

[image: Roots of Unity Plotted]

Finally, just scale by the magnitude.

Comment: I understand, but the solution in the book where I found this problem is $32^{\frac{1}{7}}(\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}+\frac{2k\pi}{7})+i\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6}+\frac{2k\pi}{7}))$, is the solution wrong?

Comment: It is not wrong.  $\text{e}^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$

Comment: Yes, but the angles are different

Comment: Notice that the 5th numbered root of unity (second from the bottom) is 5/6 pi.  Because roots of unity are cyclic, it does not matter which you start from.

Comment: So actually I got the right solution, just not in exponential form?

Comment: It could have stood to be simplified a bit, but yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

you have :

$$(-\sqrt{3}-i)^{\frac{5}{7}}=\frac{1}{2^{5/7}}\left(\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)^{5/7}=\frac{1}{2^{5/7}} \left(\exp{\frac{i7\pi}{6}}\right)^{5/7}=\frac{1}{2^{5/7}}\exp{\frac{i5\pi}{6}} $$